# Perl convert localtime to unix (epoch) time

Tags: perl, date, unix-timestamp, epoch

using perl, I am trying to estimate the time since a file was created.
I would like to convert the local time to unix time (epoch), then take unix time of the file & subtract.

The problem I face is that when I convert localtime to unixtime , it is converted incorrectly!

```
my $current = str2time (localtime(time));
print $current;
```

The results I get are

```
2768504400 = Sun, 23 Sep 2057 21:00:00 GMT
2421349200 = Sun, 23 Sep 2046 21:00:00 GMT
```

Do I have to feed str2time with a specific date format?

Comment: See http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/HTTP/Date.pm#str2time($str_[,_$zone]) for a list of supported formats.

Comment: Why don't you use [time](http://p3rl.org/time) directly?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the unix time of the file? Why not use perl's stat function to get the last modified date/time of the file and compare apples to apples? Like `perl -e 'print("LMD: ",scalar(localtime((stat("README.md"))[9])),"\nNOW: ",scalar(localtime(time())),"\n")'`, which yields: `LMD: Thu Sep 17 12:08:58 2015` and `NOW: Thu Sep 24 10:58:38 2015`

Comment: `str2time` isn't a built-in function, but there are several CPAN modules that have something by that name. Which one are you using?

Comment: ..delete me please..

Answer (score 9):

You're doing something bizarre here - `localtime(time)` takes - the epoch time (`time`) and converts it to a string.

And then you convert it back.

Just use `time()`

Or perhaps better yet `-M` which tells you how long ago a file was modified. (In days, so you'll have to multiply up).

e.g.:

```
my $filename = "sample.csv";
my $modification = -M $filename;
print $modification * 84600;
```

But if you really want to take the time and convert it back again - you'll need to look at how `localtime(time)` returns the result.

If you do:

```
print localtime(time);
```

You get:

```
5671624811542661
```

Because `localtime` is being evaluated in a list context, and so returning an array of values. (Which you can use without needing to parse).

```
 my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =
                                                localtime(time);
```

If you do it in a scalar context, it returns a string denoting the time:

```
print "".localtime(time);
```

Gives:

```
Thu Sep 24 16:09:33 2015
```

But note - that might vary somewhat depending on your current locale. That's *probably* why [`str2time`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm) is doing odd things - because it makes certain assumptions about formats that don't always apply. The big gotcha is this:

> When both the month and the date are specified in the date as numbers they are always parsed assuming that the month number comes before the date. This is the usual format used in American dates.

You would probably be better off instead using `Time::Piece` and `strftime` to get a fixed format:

e.g.

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime(time) -> strftime ( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" );
```

Note - `Time::Piece` overloads `localtime` so you can actually use it (fairly) transparently. Of course, then you can *also* do:

```
print localtime(time) -> epoch;
```

And do without all the fuss of converting back and forth.

Comment: `use Time::Piece; localtime(time)->strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` is an expensive way to write `use POSIX qw( strftime ); strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime(time))`

Comment: use Time::Piece;
    my $time = Time::Piece->new;
    my $current = $time->localtime;
    my $current2 = $time->localtime->epoch;
    
    $current is Thu Sep 24 19:26:19 2015
    
    $current2 is 1443111979 , equal to Thu, 24 Sep 2015 16:26:19 GMT

Why timezone is being lost?

Answer (score 2):

You have missed requesting localtime to produce scalar (string) instead of array.

```
use Date::Parse;
my $current = str2time (scalar(localtime(time)));
print $current, "\n";
print scalar(localtime($current)),"\n";
```

`perldoc -f localtime`

> Converts a time as returned by the time function to a 9-element
> list with the time analyzed for the local time zone. Typically
> used as follows:
> #  0    1    2     3     4    5     6     7     8
> ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) =  localtime(time);
> ...
> **In scalar context, "localtime()" returns the ctime(3) value:
>
> $now_string = localtime;  # e.g., "Thu Oct 13 04:54:34 1994"**